# Set Kendo DataSource's sort AND group at once with only a single network call?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, datasource, kendo-datasource

I'm using a Kendo DataGrid and want to programmatically set the sort and the group of its datasource without it making 2 separate network calls to get the data. The datasource is using a Web API OData URL, serverPaging, serverFiltering, serverSorting are all set to true.

The following results in 2 separate network calls:

```
grid.dataSource.sort([{ field: "Name", dir: "asc" }]);
grid.dataSource.group([{ "field": "Region", "dir": "asc" }]);
```

Is there any way to achieve a programmatic sorting/grouping in a single request?

Comment: I don't really known KendoUI but perhaps a solution is to define a _OData-like_ analysis service using (server-side) the `QueryByCube` LINQ extension method provided by [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com). Disclaimer: I'm the AdaptiveLINQ developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [query](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-query) method of the data source:

```
dataSource.query( { 
 sort: [ /* sort descriptors */], 
 group: [ /* group descriptors */ ], 
 page: dataSource.page(), 
 pageSize: dataSource.pageSize() 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My syntax was a little different but it work well

```
datasource.query({
    sort: { field: "Sort", dir: "asc"},
    group: { field: "CategoryName" },
    pageSize: 50
});
```